# Creating dynamic resource in cookbook

Tags: ruby, cookbook, chef-infra

Long story short, here is my code:

```
template "...." do

    ....

    notifies :restart,"service[myservice_One]"
    notifies :restart,"service[myservice_Two]"
end

['One', 'Two'].each do |proj|
    service 'myservice_#{proj}' do 
        start_command "setsid /etc/init.d/my_command #{proj} start"
        stop_command "setsid /etc/init.d/my_command #{proj} stop"
        restart_command "setsid /etc/init.d/my_command #{proj} restart"
        status_command "setsid /etc/init.d/my_command #{proj} status"
        supports :status => true, :restart => true
        action [:enable,:start]
    end
end
```

I got this error:

```
template[...] is configured to notify resource service[celery_worker_One] with action restart, but service[celery_worker_One] cannot be found in the resource collection.
```

I know I can duplicate my code to make it work but how to dynamically create the services?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to put template under service block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby,

```
'myservice_#{proj}'
```

and

```
"myservice_#{proj}"
```

are very different:

```
'myservice_#{proj}' #=> "myservice_#{proj}"
"myservice_#{proj}" #=> "myservice_One"
```

If you need [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation), you must use double quotes. This is why you cannot notify your resource.

Comment: Thanks. After that I need to specify `service_name "myservice"` to map to the same script.